# HR Schema Not spooling correctly

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Created HR Using

```
create user hr identified by hr
default tablespace users
temporary tablespace temp
profile default
quota  unlimited on users;
```

and connected to SQL Developer, also Unzipped the HR Schema in C Drive.
But while Executing the commands I am Unable to add HR Schema to my SQL Developer.

```
Parameter 1 :: hr
Parameter 2 :: users
Parameter 3 :: temp
Parameter 4 :: { used my password} 
Parameter 5 :: $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log
Parameter 6 :: localhost:1521/XEPDB1

@ C:\app\guru1\product\21c\dbhomeXE\demo\schema\human_resources\hr_main.sql
```

[I am getting the Error as
[not spooling currently
Connection created by CONNECT script command disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDD1K.png)

Comment: What is contents of that .SQL script? Did you check it? If not, do so. If you can't figure it out, share it with the community as it is difficult to debug code you can't see.

Comment: Spooling won't stop your objects being created and loaded